# Is it possible to hide custom picklist field dependent on other picklist in Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I currently have an aura component where I have multiple fields for data entry from user. I want to add a picklist field based on the users answer from other picklist value.

For eg:-  Do you live in Canada? This picklist has value Yes/ No.
if the user Selects Yes then that user should be able to see Province__c picklist field and should be able to select value. If users selects No then that user should not be able to see that that field.

Is this functionality possible using aura component or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using conditional rendering of the subsequent picklists via the `<aura:if>` tag.

The Aura developer documentation covers this under the [Conditional Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm) and [Best Practices for Conditional Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_conditional_markup.htm) articles.